# Suppressing CA-rules in Stylecop

Tags: c#, stylecop

I'm working down a list of stylecop-warnings, of which some I simply want to suppress. However, after working down the SA list with the [help of StyleCop's own documentation](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ReSharper%20Fixes), I found that the CA-warnings are not documented by StyleCop. I'm having a pretty hard time finding a list of CA-warnings and their rule-category/rule-longname, which I need to be able to suppress them (as [stated by StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rule%20Suppressions&referringTitle=Documentation))..

Specifically CA1822 is what I'm trying to find as of now. A "Back-up method", whom's execution is written like

```
this.MyList = this.MethodReturnsAList() ?? this.BackUpMethod();
```

is being flagged as 'never used'. I don't want to make the method static, so I figured I'd suppress the message to clear my log. According to [the MSDN-page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms245046.aspx), it shouldn't pose any problems.

Any help as to where I could find CA-ruling descriptions would be much appreciated, though currently I'd settle for an alternative to making the warning disappear..

Comment: You can [suppress code analysis warnings by using an attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CA warnings are not Style Cop warnings. They are nothing but Code Analysis warnings. You can pretty much find the rule descriptions of them in MSDN itself. For this particular warning please refer [CA1822: Mark members as static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245046.aspx)

Comment: That page I found, so assuming the rule-category and rule-longname I need (as referenced in the main-post) are to be found here, where are they found?

Comment: I think I found the root cause which cause this warning in your code. I suspect the method MethodReturnsTruOrFalse returns a boolean value. But you have checked it with a ?? operator which checks for a null of the left side operand and if it is null it returns the right hand side operand. Since bool is non-nullable, the compiler says the method on the right hand side of ?? operator as never used.

Comment: That's on me, I was supposed to write `ReturnsAList()`, but for some reason got stuck with a boolean in my head. However, it still returns an empty list (so not null), which is effectively the same as you stated. So that solves this warning, but I'm still curious where I can find the properties I need on that MSDN-page ?

Comment: You can suppress in it the below way
[Scope:SuppressMessage("Rule Category", "Rule Id", Justification = "Justification", MessageId = "MessageId", Scope = "Scope", Target = "Target")]  
For this you need only the Rule Category and Rule ID which you can find in the page I gave above. For you convenience Rule Category : Microsoft.Performance Rule Id : CA1822

Comment: I don't want a global suppression, because in other instances the warning is valid and needs to be resolved. I just want to suppress it in this specific case..

Comment: You can define the scope of the suppression, when you do it in this way in the Scope attribute. Please refer 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx

Comment: Yeess, got it. That article did it in for me, thanks !